# persistent pip install in rapids.ai docker container

Tags: docker, pip, pytorch, rapids

This is probably a really stupid question, but one has got to start somewhere. I am playing with NVDIA's rapids.ai gpu-enhanced docker container, but this (presumably by design) does not come with pytorch. Now, of course, I can do a `pip install torch torch-ignite` every time, but this is both annoying and resource-consuming (and pytorch is a large download). What is the approved method for persisting a `pip install` in a container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new `Dockerfile` that builds a new image based on the existing one:

```
FROM the/rapids-ai/image

RUN pip install torch torch-ignite
```

And then

```sh
$ ls Dockerfile
Dockerfile
$ docker build -t myimage .
```

You can now do:

```sh
$ docker run myimage
```